# The cyclotomic polynomial analogue for $A_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, symmetric-groups

It is well known that the cyclotomic polynomials encode all the cyclic groups of order $p-1$ for $p$ prime; that is, in the form of a Galois Group of the polynomial $x^p-1$. Concretely we have that

$$F_p(x)=x^p-1 = \prod_{d|p} \Phi_d(x)=(1-x)\left(1+ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} x^k \right). $$

See "Contemporary Abstract Algebra, Seventh Edition, Joseph A. Gallian, 'Cyclotomic Polynomials, page 562 and Theorem 33.1 on the same page'"

While these are not the only polynomials having the cyclic group of order $p-1$, say $C_{p-1}$, as their Galois Group, this polynomial is in some sense the "simplest" polynomial that encodes $C_{p-1}$ in the form of a Galois Group.

The question: what is the analogue for the alternating group $A_n$? That is, what does $F_q(x)$ look like such that it encodes all the groups of the form $A_q$ in this "simple" or canonical sense? Where $q$ would be the analogue of prime numbers.

Comment: The Galois group of $\Phi_n(x)$ isn't $C_n$, it's $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, you are correct. The question has been corrected accordingly.

Comment: Your displayed equation looks strange: $x^p-1$ has just *two* factors: $x-1$ and $x^{p-1} + \cdots + x + 1$, so writing an abstract-looking product over the factors of $p$ is kind of excessive even if it is logically correct. It would be like writing $x^2-1 = \Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(x)$ instead of $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: @KCd, yes. That is the notation Gallian used, and given that the answer will most likely use that notation I'd prefer to leave it there. That notation even for your $x^2-1$ case can be useful when teaching. I did expand further to your point.

Comment: Sure, but it's like writing $\varphi(p) = p(\sum_{d \mid p} \mu(d)/d)$ instead of $\varphi(p) = p-1$.

Comment: @KCd: the notation will remain as is. That is all.